# How to handle in app purchases with Dynamic Products

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

We have scenario where user needs to pay for every videos that are uploaded in backend/admin.

To achieve this we have to use Non-Consumable product by default but the limitation is to have the product created manually on appstore/playstore.

**Consumable**
Provide different types of consumables, such as lives or gems used to further progress in a game, boosts in a dating app to increase profile visibility, or digital tips for creators within a social media app. Consumable in‑app purchases are depleted as they’re used and can be purchased again. They’re frequently offered in apps and games that use the freemium business model.

**Non-consumable**
Provide non-consumable, premium features that are purchased once and don’t expire. Examples include additional filters in a photo app, extra brushes in an illustration app, or cosmetic items in a game. Non-consumable in-app purchases can offer Family Sharing.

My question is, according to business need we have to choose the Non-Consumeable product because it gives lifetime access to the item, but on appstore we have to create **consumable** product because it allows you to purchase again. i am confuse between consumable or non-consumable with the business requirement.

Pricing of the videos are same 25$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **Non-consumable purchased once is based on AppleID**, which means if you have multi-user and use same AppleID, it will restore automatically without buying again. **In other words, it may become a risk to your business model.** (Underground economy may use one AppleID to buy all movies and share the AppleID at a good price)

For your case, you may implement your requirements with followings steps:

1. Use **Consumable** product to buy for some coins(your server managed)
2. When user buy movie, consume their coins and provide movies
3. Your movies should be related with your app accounts instead of AppleID, so your server should sync the movies with app accounts

You may also use **Consumable** product to buy movies directly(description maybe like "25$ movies"), but it maybe contains an audit risk, for Apple may reject with reason "Using common product for purchase and product description is not detailed enough"